# How to attach a pixie render to the babylon.js mesh or move the pixie container along the axis Z

Tags: javascript, 3d, 2d, pixi.js, babylonjs

If I combine `pixi.js` and `babylon.js` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y5q7Lb1v/40/) than I want change container with `pixi.js` assets along the axis Z.

For example I would like to do:

```
stage.position.set(100, 100, 100);
```

But I can set only X and Y coordinates.

```
stage.position.set(100, 100);
```

Maybe it’s possible to somehow bind the render `pixi.js` to some kind of `mesh` of the `babylon.js`?

I would like to be able to zoom in or out the picture drawn through the render `pixi.js` inside the 3D world.

UPD: I made an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8L31j9pe/) which to insert a canvas from the `pixi.js` render into the `HtmlElementTexture` but I see the animation separately from the plane.